# Having some trouble with Learn Python The Hard Way Excercise 48

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the section we are given a series of unit tests and need to create a function that will make the tests pass. Here is the test:

```
from nose.tools import *
from testing import *


def test_numbers():
    assert_equal(scan("1234"), [('number', 1234)])
    result = scan("3 91234")
    assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
                      ('number', 91234)])
```

There are other aspects of the tests but this is the only one that isn't passing. Here is what I wrote:

```
def convert_number(s):
    try: 
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def scan(s):

    direction_words= ("north", "south", "east", "west", "down", "up", "left", "right", "back")
    verbs= ("go", "stop", "kill", "eat")
    stop_words= ("the", "in", "of", "from", "at", "it")
    nouns= ("door", "bear", "princess", "cabinet")        
    numbers= s.split()
    i=0
    j=0
    g=0
    m=0
    a=0


    while a< len(numbers):
        if  type(convert_number(numbers[a])) == int:
            return [('number', int(x) ) for x in s.split()]
        else:
            a += 1


    while i < 9:
        if direction_words[i] in s.split():
            return [('direction', x ) for x in s.split()]
        else:
            i+=1              

    while j < 4:
        if verbs[j] in s.split():
            return [('verb', x ) for x in s.split()]
        else:
            j+=1

    while g < 6:
         if stop_words[g] in s.split():
             return [('stop', x ) for x in s.split()]
         else:
            g+=1

    while m < 4:
         if nouns[m] in s.split():
             return [('noun', x ) for x in s.split()] 
        else:
            m+=1

    else:
        return
```

Comment: May I recommend that you post this code on codereview.stackexchange.com? You'll get some advice on how to make it cleaner and just generally better.

Comment: Its best not to update your post with fixed code. If you want to include the fixed code add it after your original code. That way the question still makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `@staticmethod` above `def scan(s):` to make it work.

Comment: When I did that it came back with this error message: NameError: global name 'convert_number' is not defined

Comment: @Adam replace `convert_number` by `lexicon.convert_number`.

Comment: @phaedrus Ok but that gave me this error message: TypeError: unbound method convert_number() must be called with lexicon instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: @Adam: You need `@staticmethod` above both `def`s. If this doesn't solve the problem, please update your question with the code you are running, and the full (multiline) error message, including line numbers and file names.

Comment: @pts  Ive been messing with the code to try and solve some of the problems, and I just updated it with the newest version and the error message I can't figure out.

Comment: @Adam: The AssertionError you get is because your `scan` method returns None, but it should return something else. There is a bug in your implementation. I think the best educational value is that you can get is if you figure out what your code is doing wrong. A suggestion: add some `print` statements and observe the output to figure out where your code is branching.

Comment: @pts I took your advice and have been working on this for a few hours. As you can see I made a lot of changes. I have established that the issue is that I can't figure out how to call my convert_number(self, s) function while in the scan class. It is the only logical thing I can think of. I'm sure I am just being stupid and don't know how to call the function from a different class.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I updated the code with the final working version.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you certainly want `def scan(self, s):` instead of `def scan(s):`.

Comment: I think he rather needs `@staticmethod`, because with your suggestion (`self`), `lexicon.scan("...")` wouldn't work, because it would require an object.